# Cannot trust current state of AAC lifecycle

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

### Issue summary

`getLifecycle().getCurrentState()` gave me wrong state.

### Environment (integrated library, OS, etc)

- compileSdkVersion : 27
- targetSdkVersion : 27
- support library : 27.1.1

### Expected behavior

- onCreate() -> CREATED
- onStart() -> STARTED
- onResume() -> RESUMED
- onPause() -> STARTED
- onStop() -> CREATED
- onDestroy() -> DESTROYED

### Actual behavior

- onCreate : **INITIALIZED**
- onStart : **CREATED**
- onResume : **STARTED**
- onPause : STARTED
- onStop : CREATED
- onDestroy : DESTROYED

### Issue detail

I tried using below code.
I searched google but no one thinks strangely about this.
Am I something missing?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.i(MainActivity::class.java.name, "onCreate : " + lifecycle.currentState.name)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Log.i(MainActivity::class.java.name, "onStart : " + lifecycle.currentState.name)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.i(MainActivity::class.java.name, "onResume : " + lifecycle.currentState.name)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.i(MainActivity::class.java.name, "onPause : " + lifecycle.currentState.name)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        Log.i(MainActivity::class.java.name, "onStop : " + lifecycle.currentState.name)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.i(MainActivity::class.java.name, "onDestroy : " + lifecycle.currentState.name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your actual behaviour is the expected behaviour if you look at the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle

[image: lifecycle]

*Think of the states as nodes of a graph and events as the edges between these nodes.*